# Using each() to g

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, loops

```
var arr = new Array();

$('.cartitem').each(function(i,obj){


    text = $(this).find('#c').text();
    number = text.split("Qty:");
    x = parseFloat(number[1]).toFixed(2.0); 

    arr.push(x);
    alert(arr.toString());



  });
```

This loop repeats the same call more than once for each item.  How can change it so it executes the function above only once for each item?

Comment: it will execute only once for an item.... how are you saying it executed more than once for an item

Comment: I am adding and removing divs to a shopping cart. Each div contains an item's total amount. After adding and removing divs to the cart, I hit the checkout button to get the order's total amount. If add 4 divs and remove 1, the code does not return 3 amounts (1 per div), but instead, it alerts 4 sets of the same 3 amounts of the divs which did not get removed.

Comment: This is how I am removing the divs

$('.cartitem img').click(function(){

  $(this).closest('div').remove();
     
  $.when($(this).closest('div').empty().remove()).then($('#cartcount').val($('.cartitem').size()+' '+'items'));
  
});

The divs are no longer visible and the item count // $('.cartitem').size() // reflects the correct size of divs.  If I add 10 divs, and remove 5, the code returns 10 sets of 5 values instead of just 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = $(this).find('#c').text();
```

Do not use ID here. ID is intended to be unique and jQuery expects it to be. jQuery could be selecting the same item over and over again because of this. Use class instead. So change your HTML and this will be

```
text = $(this).find('.c').text();
```

Comment: that made no difference